# Python - A way to make interactive a script execution in console

Tags: python, django, stdout, stdin

I'm working on a web interface for the Django migrate/makemigrations commands. I've been checking the code, an they use the Python `input()` to get the answers of the [questions](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/questioner.py).

At the moment I have tried to use the Python `subprocess` library in order to answer by an external script (a Python script running a Python script).

I have generated a simple script that could be useful as a test:

**sum.py**

```
first_number = input("Welcome to the program that sum two numbers, \
please give me the first number: ")
second_number = input("Now, please give me the second number: ")
print("Congratulations, the result of the sum of %s and %s is: %s" % 
      (first_number, second_number, (first_number + second_number)))
```

And the only way that I've found to make the script runs the first script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = ["python", "sum.py"]
p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("1\n")
p.stdin.write("2\n")
print p.communicate()[0]
```

I've found in internet some days ago some code to make a ping an receive like real time the stdout:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = ["ping", "192.168.1.137"]
p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, )
while p.poll() is None:
    print p.stdout.readline()
```

I've modified the code and tried to run the script:

64 bytes from 192.168.1.137: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.655 ms
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

```
command = ["python", "suma.py"]
p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, )
response = "1\n"
while p.poll() is None:
    print p.stdout.readline() #Obtain the message
    p.stdin.write(response) #Answer the question
```

I've found some possibles ways with websockets and node.js like [tty.js](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/) or [web-console](https://github.com/rabchev/web-terminal), but it could be hard of mantain since I have no much idea of the programming language.

What I find is to receive and send to an HTML page the message from stdout and get the response from the user.

I'm a bit lost, any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with pure Django: you need an evented server such as Twisted or Gevent or similar to make this work. Traditional web frameworks like Django can't do realtime update service. You can follow any Chat tutorials, this is exactly the same like chat except for where your messages are coming from and ending up at.

Comment: Regardless the use of the Django framework, I haven't even make this work in terminal. :/
Thanks for the advice of servers.